# HTML Tags Stripped in PHP AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a hard time understanding why html tags are being stripped from an ajax call but here's very simple code and screenshots to match:

**JS**

```
function submitForm()
{
    var data = { description: '<b>Something</b>' };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/edit',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
public function edit()
{
    var_dump($_POST['description']);exit;
}
```

**HEADERS SCREENSHOT**

[image: screenshot-1]

**RESPONSE SCREENSHOT**

[image: screenshot-2]

Does anyone know why the response does not show the `<b></b>` tag that's in the header?

Comment: try to set content-Type to text/html

Comment: in update function use this echo strip_tags();

Comment: Because you're removing it somewhere.

Comment: if you are using a framework the framework might remove them

Comment: @madalinivascu I'm using the Fat Free Framework. Any experience with it?

Comment: Found this in the docs. http://fatfreeframework.com/base#clean

Comment: http://fatfreeframework.com/views-and-templates view data sainitisation at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$f3->scrub($_POST,'p; br; span; div; b; a');`

Comment: I feel like you're on to something but it's not working for me. I've tried placing it where I'm echoing the $_POST, in my construct and explicitly in the page route. Still the same result.

Comment: This is technically the right answer but wanted to clarify what was happening. I found a loop inside of app.php that removed all tags from ALL user input (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) using ```$f3->clean()```and had to modify it to whitelist the tags that Stack Exchange whitelist (courtesy of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites). Thanks for your help!